# CSS How to make element in the middle to shrink before its sibling jumps down

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<divs>` in a parent `<div>` they all are `inline-block`

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bht0ny5/1/)

When I reduce the width of window 'Continue button' jumps down

[image]

while what I want is for 'Please click continue to purchase' wrap till it is shrank to nothing before 'Continue' jumps down.

[image]

Continue button has fixed `width : 127px`and background is sprite.

I have tried adding `%` and `em` widths to 'Please click continue to purchase' but what happens it wraps last word while 'Continue' button still jumps down. Adding fixed width on 'Please click continue to purchase' is not an option since requirement is that it has to be one line for as long as possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="-ms-overflow-y: scroll;">
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
 display: block;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
}
html {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
a {
 background: transparent;
}
*::before, *::after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.price-and-button {
 display: block;
}
.premium-wrapper {
 border: 3px solid #2280c4;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 15px;
}
.legal.premium-wrapper {
 border-radius: 30px;
 border-width: 2px;
 padding-left: 3em;
 padding-right: 3em;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper {
 border: 1px solid #2280c4;
 *zoom: 1: ;
}
.premium-wrapper.legal::before, .premium-wrapper.legal::after {
 content: none;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper::before, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper::before, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper::before, .lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper::after, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper::after, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper::after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
 line-height: 0;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper::after, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper::after, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper::after {
 clear: both;
}
.sections-wrapper {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.left-column {
 margin: 38px 0 0 76px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 1px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
 float: left;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
.col-md-8 {
 width: 66.66%;
}
.row {
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */
.container {
 width: 1010px;
}
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after, .container::before, .container::after, .container-fluid::before, .container-fluid::after, .row::before, .row::after, .nav::before, .nav::after, .navbar::before, .navbar::after, .navbar-header::before, .navbar-header::after, .navbar-collapse::before, .navbar-collapse::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::before, .form-horizontal .form-group::after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}
.clearfix::after, .container::after, .container-fluid::after, .row::after, .nav::after, .navbar::after, .navbar-header::after, .navbar-collapse::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::after {
 clear: both;
}
.content-container {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-height: 400px;
 box-shadow: 25px 0px 25px -25px #333333, -25px 0px 25px -25px #333333;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
}
.container {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
.container {
 width: 750px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
.container {
 width: 970px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */
.container {
 width: 1170px;
}
.body-wrap {
 background: url(../images/saga-home/background-gradient.png) repeat-x;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 min-height: 500px;
}
body {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.4285;
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
body {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #333333;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
html {
 font-size: 62.5%;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.price-and-button-cell {
 display: inline-block;
}
.please-click-to-continue {
 padding-right: 0.7em;
 position: relative;
 top: -15px;
}
.bottom-buttons, .summary-group-bottom-buttons, .premium-bottom-buttons {
 margin-top: 30px;
 min-height: 38px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.legal.bottom-buttons {
 width: 130px;
 top: -2px;
}
.button-and-shadow-container {
 float: right;
}
.bottom-buttons .button-and-shadow-container, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-and-shadow-container, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-and-shadow-container {
 float: right;
}
a {
 color: #428bca;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a {
 color: #0088cc;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper a, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper a, .summary-fee-breakdown a {
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.bottom-buttons .button-green-small, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-small, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-small, .bottom-buttons .button-blue-small, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-blue-small, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-blue-small, .bottom-buttons .button-green-medium, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-medium, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-medium, .bottom-buttons .button-blue-medium, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-blue-medium, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-blue-medium, .bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .bottom-buttons .button-blue-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-blue-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-blue-large, .bottom-buttons .button-green-extra-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-extra-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-extra-large, .bottom-buttons .button-green-extra-large-lm, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-extra-large-lm, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-extra-large-lm, .bottom-buttons .button-blue-extra-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-blue-extra-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-blue-extra-large {
 border: none;
 color: #f2f5fd;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 700;
 height: 38px;
 line-height: 38px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .bottom-buttons .button-blue-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-blue-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-blue-large {
 width: 135px;
}
.bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .summary-group-bottom-buttons .button-green-large, .premium-bottom-buttons .button-green-large {
 background: #16C52F 0 -304px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin: 9px 0;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #2280c4;
 text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
 line-height: 36px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
}
.premium-wrapper h2 {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.premium-wrapper h2:first-child {
 margin: 0;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper h2 {
 *zoom: 1: ;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2::before, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2::before, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper h2::before, .lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2::after, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2::after, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper h2::after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
 line-height: 0;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2::after, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2::after, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper h2::after {
 clear: both;
}
.legal.premium-wrapper h2.your-quote {
 padding: 0;
 width: 6em;
}
.premium-wrapper h2 span {
 display: block;
}
.premium-wrapper h2 span + span {
 color: #333333;
 font-size: 18.2px;
 line-height: 20px;
}
.lpa-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2 span, .conveyancing-quote-wrapper .premium-wrapper h2 span, .summary-fee-breakdown .premium-wrapper h2 span {
 float: left;
}
.legal.premium-wrapper h2 span + span {
 color: #2280c4;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 36px;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="sections-wrapper"><section><div class="premium-wrapper legal "><div class="price-and-button">
                        <div style="display: block;">
                            <div class="price-and-button-cell">
                                <h2 class="your-quote">
                                    <span>Your Quote</span>
                                    <span>
                                        £847.20
                                    </span>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-and-button-cell magic-magic-disappear please-click-to-continue">Please click continue to purchase</div>
                            <div class="bottom-buttons legal price-and-button-cell">
                                <div class="button-and-shadow-container">
                                    <a class="button-green-large" href="/legal-services/Lpa/customerDetails?product=Property%20and%20finance%20AND%20health%20and%20welfare">Continue</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></div></section></div></div></div></div></form></div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

**How to make element in the middle to shrink before its sibling jumps down?**

Comment: Currently it doesn't jump down.

Comment: @ManojKumar one sec, IE copy html with style was misbehaving, had to delete part from top of page. Now it shows it in full page mode

Comment: was there any need to copy your whole website styles and codes to the fiddle??

Comment: @RohitKumar I only now realised that when one does 'copy element with styles' on IE it takes bunch of parent elements and does weird stuff to them

Comment: @RohitKumar now sorted both JSFiddle and Script on page, sorry about that.

Comment: I asked about removing unnecessary styles and elements which are of no use..

Comment: @RohitKumar how would you know which to remove?

Comment: see which elements are used in your html snippet and add styles only to those elements. like you don't have `article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, summary` tags in your html, so you can remove these from your styles in the beginning, just like that there is too much junk and with this you are likely to not get attention of users to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86782/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-matas-vaitkevicius).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you're only targeting modern browsers else you can do something with css table layout for older browsers.

```
.wrapper {display:table;}
.wrapper div {display:table-cell; padding:10px;}
@media only screen and (max-width:300px) {
    .wrapper div {display:inline-block;}
}
```

Here's a snippet (below) but its much easier to resize in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zx9rv2ad/)

```css
.wrapper {display:table;}
.wrapper div {display:table-cell; padding:10px;}

@media only screen and (max-width:300px) {
    .wrapper div {display:inline-block;}
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'> 
    <div class='first'>Your Quote</div>
    <div class='second'>Please click to enable purchase</div>
    <div class='third'>Buy now</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved in multiple ways depending upon your need( Browser Support).

## Media Query

You could change the width of `.please-click-to-continue` div when it reaches a threshold value. Assuming threshold to be `600px`...

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    .please-click-to-continue {
        width:100px; /* or whatever works for you.*/
    }
}
```

This however *may not be a cleaner way* since you wouldn't be sure how much space is available. Here comes **flexbox**

## Flexbox

#### Browser Support( from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) ) -

- Chrome any
- Firefox any
- Safari any
- Opera 12.1+
- IE 10+
- iOS any
- Android any

Flexbox provides native and clean way of space distribution among elements. Take the following example and modify based on your needs.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left,
.center,
.right {
  height: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px;
}
.center {
  background: #ff0066;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

## Table

There is a table way of doing it which I am not going to write about as @Moob has already mentioned in his answer while I was writing this one. :)

Comment: background : #bada55 , made my day :)

Comment: that's my go to color for demos :p ;)